# Why do I get "argument "output" is missing, with no default" when trying to make a sankey plot with R shiny and networkD3?

Tags: r, shiny, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I am trying to make a shiny App in R via the networkD3 example. My code is attached on the bottom.

I got the code from [this page](https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/tree/master/inst/examples/shiny).

When I try to run this, I get this error message:

```
Error in shinyServer(function(input, output) { : 
  argument "output" is missing, with no default
```

Question: How do I fix the code to make it work?

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Shiny networkD3 "),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("opacity", "Opacity", 0.6, min = 0.1, max = 1, step = .1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Simple Network", simpleNetworkOutput("simple")),
        tabPanel("Force Network", forceNetworkOutput("force")),
        tabPanel("Force Network with Legend & Radius", forceNetworkOutput("forceRadius")),
        tabPanel("Sankey Network", 
                 checkboxInput("sinksRight", "sinksRight", value = TRUE),
                 sankeyNetworkOutput("sankey")),
        tabPanel("Reingold-Tilford Tree", radialNetworkOutput("rt"))
      )
    )
  )
))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$sankey <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    URL <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json"
    Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)
    sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
                  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                  fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30, sinksRight = input$sinksRight)
  })



})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign your `UI` to ui, and your `server` function to a variable called `server`. Those are then passed as arguments in your last line `shinyApp(ui,server)`. Hope this helps!

Working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Shiny networkD3 "),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("opacity", "Opacity", 0.6, min = 0.1, max = 1, step = .1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Simple Network", simpleNetworkOutput("simple")),
        tabPanel("Force Network", forceNetworkOutput("force")),
        tabPanel("Force Network with Legend & Radius", forceNetworkOutput("forceRadius")),
        tabPanel("Sankey Network", 
                 checkboxInput("sinksRight", "sinksRight", value = TRUE),
                 sankeyNetworkOutput("sankey")),
        tabPanel("Reingold-Tilford Tree", radialNetworkOutput("rt"))
      )
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output) {


  output$sankey <- renderSankeyNetwork({
    URL <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json"
    Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)
    sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
                  Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                  fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30, sinksRight = input$sinksRight)
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```